# Form a strictly decreasing subsequence with $a_{F+ 1}$ as its first term.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If an arbitrary sequence contains just a finite number of floor terms, and the last one is $a_F$, form a strictly decreasing subsequence with $a_{F+ 1}$ as its first term.

We call a term of a sequence a ‘floor term’ when none of its successors is strictly less. Given that definition I am not sure how to construct such a sequence. One (non)-example is $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1000000, 1000000 - 1,\ldots, 1000000 - n, \ldots$ For our purposes, no term after $5$ should be less than $5$, but in this sequence that's not guaranteed. The only way I see this working is if the strictly decreasing subsequence is finite, like so $1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94 \ldots$ where all the terms after $94$ are $94.$

Is it possible to have a sequence with a finite number of floor terms and one of whose subsequences is strictly decreasing and infinite? I can't seem to think of one. Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow. Would it suffice to take $a_{F+i}=a_F+\frac 1i$?

Comment: I am trying to make sense of [this answer](http://s10.postimg.org/mqv02eqt5/Capture333.png) to the given question. I am not  sure if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I don't see that as a constructive answer, just as an (accurate) observation.  The writer is saying "suppose you have a sequence such that $a_F$ is the last floor term.  Then $a_{F+1}$ is not a floor term so we can find some $a_{F+k}<a_{F+1}$  But then $a_{F+k}$ is also not a floor term so we can find some $a_{F+k+m}<a_{F+k}$ and so on, thereby obtaining a strictly decreasing subsequence.

Comment: Thanks. I see. But I am still not sure how to construct at least a specific example of such a sequence. Can you, please, give an example.

Comment: My example works.  Suppose, for clarity that $a_1=0$ is the only floor term.  Then for $i>1$ we define $a_i=\frac 1i$  That is a strictly decreasing, and all of the terms past the first are strictly greater than $a_1$.

Comment: Oh! Perfect and very clever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously,
only the last decreasing subsequence
can be infinite.

Since
$(n+1)^2
=n^2+2n+1
$,
for each $n$
do
$(n+1)^2, (n+1)^2-1,
(n+1)^2-2, ... (n+1)^2-2n
$
as many times as you want.

To finish with
an infinite decreasing
subsequence,
do
$n^2-\sum_{k=0}^m \frac1{2^k}
$ 
for each successive $m$.

Also obviously,
any infinite decreasing sequence
of integers
has to go to 
$-\infty$,
so non-integers
have to be used 
for the last sequence.